# Highlighting text after clicking a link in pdf

Tags: xml, pdf, dita

I am using **DITA** to create .pdf files.

How do I make a 1-3 second highlight of text that I'm referring to with a link?

e.g. I click a link, which redirects to a phrase (picture, table, etc.), which is then highlighted for a few seconds.

Comment: You might be able to do this with some embedded JavaScript. I don't know how you would get it through your FO processor, but I think it's a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this could work using `<fo:multi-properties>`, but this is not supported by any of the DITA-OT formatters (FOP, XEP, Antenna), see: [6.9 Dynamic Effects: Link and Multi Formatting Objects](https://www.data2type.de/en/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/formatter-comparison/)

```
<fo:block>
  <fo:multi-properties>
    <fo:multi-property-set active-state="hover" color="red"/>
    <fo:wrapper>
      <fo:basic-link external-destination="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</fo:basic-link>
    </fo:wrapper>
  </fo:multi-properties>
</fo:block>
```